# General questions to regex, conditions and if-statement

Tags: c#, regex

I had a beginning question to read in a two digit number and give it back splittet into its numbers but I soon saw, that the code I created was not really handy, when wrong inputs where done.

So I did a research about if-statemants, .length feature, regex method and comperative operators. What came back was my rudimental first script for input a two digit number, prove if it is 2 digits long, prove if it is a number and give it back. Now I have some questions to You specialists (it is a console application btw.):

1. Was it the right way to use regex with the IsMatch method, or would be another method saver and cleaner (maybe also another variant of regex)
2. Is it possible to shorten the code, Iam not so far atm, maybe there are classes or objects to use, to make the code clearer.
3. Was it the right way to use conditional "and" instead of regular "and", in the if statements?
4. Are the if statements possible to be shorten, I read about conditional expressions, but I was not sure how far I could nest them (my reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). Maybe some of You can give me an example on my script.
5. Is the new operator on regex the right way to implement it, or is there another way to implement regex?

The script works, but maybe there are better and handier solutions.

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TwoDigitSplit
{
    class FromTrexToRegex
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int digit, digit1, digit2;
            string entry;
            // Search for one or more decimal numbers with Regex
            Regex regex = new Regex("[0-9]+");
            // Read in a two-digit number
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a two-digit number:");
            entry = Console.ReadLine();
            // Check for length longer than two-digit and also check if it is numbers 
            if (entry.Length>2 && regex.IsMatch(entry))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number is longer than two-digit, please try again!");
            }
            // Check for length smaller than two-digit and also check if it is numbers 
            else if (entry.Length<2 && regex.IsMatch(entry))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number is shorter than two-digit, please try again!");
            }
            // Check for integer numbers and if the number is between 10 inklusiv and 100 exklusiv
            else if(Int32.TryParse(entry, out digit) && digit >= 10 && digit <100)
            {
                // Evaluate the number and write it
                digit1= digit / 10;
                digit2 = digit % 10;
                Console.WriteLine("The number has on the first place {0} and on the second place {1}", digit1, digit2);
            }
            // If no number has been plottet
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a number!");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

There are no error results atm. I could see, I only had some questions about the methods, classes and operators.

Comment: Pattern for **2** digit number is `^[0-9]{2}$`: `^` - beginning of the string then `[0-9]{2}` - exactly **2** digits, finally `$` - end of the string

Comment: @DmitryBychenko. or: `^\d{2}$`

Comment: If your code works and you're instead after some critiques of it, there's another site on the network for that: [codereview.se].  Just make sure your question is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for them.

Comment: Alternative Linq validation: `entry.Length == 2 && entry.All(c => c >= '0' && c <='9')`

Comment: `digit1 = entry[0] - '0'` and `digit2 = entry[1] - '0'` (no need to parse and do arithmetics)

Comment: I'd ditch the whole regex part and just `.TryParse()` and work on the result. Checking the string length and int range is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the hints @(DmitryBychenko, Sea Sharp, Filburt). Also thanks to James Thorpe for the Code Review hint, sorry I did not know this.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the hint Zohar Peled, I will handle it that way in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers

1. `regex = new Regex(...) ... regex.IsMatch(...)` is possible, but I suggest static `Regex.IsMatch` as more readable here
2. Yes, some conditions are redundant
3. I suggest separated regex condition (testing for value) and length (testing for length)
4. Ternary operator `? :` must return a value, in you case you want to call a method - `Console.WriteLine`; stick to `if`
5. `regex = new Regex(...)` is possible, but I don't think it's good in the context. You want to test just once: `Regex.IsMatch(...)` is more readable

Code:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a two-digit number:");

    // Trim: let us be nice and tolerate leading and trailing spaces 
    // (esp. in case user put it with copy-pasting)
    entry = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

    // Just check the length
    if (entry.Length > 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The number is longer than two-digit, please try again!");
    }
    // Check for length smaller than two-digit 
    else if (entry.Length < 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The number is shorter than two-digit, please try again!");
    }
    // The length is correct, time to check the value
    else if (!Regex.IsMatch(entry, "^[0-9]{2}$")) // <- just a static method
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The input is not 2 digit number, please try again!")
    }
    // The entry is valid, let's ptint the result out
    else 
    {
       // You don't have to parse and do arithmetic 
       // if you want to convert char to corresponding digit: '7' -> 7
       int digit1 = entry[0] - '0';
       int digit2 = entry[1] - '0';

       // String interpolation is often more readable than formatting
       Console.WriteLine(
          $"The number has on the first place {digit1} and on the second place {digit2}");
    }
```

Comment: Dimitry Bychenko you made my day! Thank You for the good advices! Really cool! I will do more research on your hints and suggestions! Thank you so much!